# Why after giving value datetime-local datetime is it not changeable?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using datetime-local to set the meeting time, try to give datetime but not showing up on output.

More, it shows up when tried on stackblitz but not on the project.

**UPDATE**

TS:

```
TODAY= new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

ngOnInit(): void { }
     
DT(name:string, time:string) { (document.getElementById(name) as HTMLTextAreaElement).value = moment(this.TODAY + 'T' + time)['_i'];  }
```

HTML:

```
<input formControlName="ab" id="ab" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" [value]="DT('ab','08:30')" required>
```

The good thing is its value datetime is appearing on the website, **the issue is after that I am not able to change datetime.**

Comment: If you want only time then please check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#validation

Comment: Its working fine for me, please check it from here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-architecture-ry1ddz?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hi @HardikSolanki yes even I don't get it why is not displaying with my project, more please check updated question

Comment: You have `double quote` issue in `property binding` for `value`. you binding should look like: `[value]="DT('ab','08:30')"`

Comment: I update code with single quote but still not able to select any other datetime.

Comment: I have update code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-architecture-ry1ddz?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hi @HardikSolanki would like to add one more think when I tried to check formcontrol json output its chnaging date their and on front handle its keep same 8:30 one

Comment: Please update your question to enhance clarity; not just add comments which may easily be missed

Comment: Your `DT` function doesn't make sense to me. It accepts `name`, which it uses to call `getElementById` and assign the `value` property of that element. It does not return anything. However, in the HTML, you're using `DT` to bind to the `value` property of the element. I would expect your `DT` function to return the value instead of assigning to the element directly.

Comment: Hello guys, I solve the issue @JackA. your absolutly right it wasn't making sense. reason I want able see on front handle is I was applying `form.reset()`. now using `this.myform.get('ab').setValue(moment(this.TODAY + 'T' + '17:15')['_i']);`